# Django Messages not showing in generic view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to show a flash message in a django app (Django 3.1), but having difficult time figuring out how:

My settings are as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proj_users.urls'

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then my generic view is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class AppIndex(generic.ListView):
   model = User
   template_name = 'users/index.html'

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       messages.success(request, "Test users flash message")
       return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
{% include 'users/_messages.html' %}
<table>
{#List of users here...#}
</table>
```

The _messages.html partial file looks like this:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <div class="alert {{messages.tags}} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                {{ message | safe }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But this doesnt seem to work in any way. Any help will be greatly appeciated.

Comment: have you added **django.contrib.messages** to install apps

Comment: I'd go over the docs. There's also the associated installed app, context processor and session middleware; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Yes its there: 'django.contrib.messages',

Comment: @FreddCha can you please show the full settings

Comment: I have updated the question, and added more detail @c.grey

Comment: I am not sure if what I am doing is correct, remember these are generic views not function based ones. I have overriden the get function to add my flash message. Maybe its getting lost somewhere during the process! I also have other views extending the SuccessMessageMixin but either way its not working.

Comment: @FreddCha try this **return super(AppIndex, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)**